# parsing variables from MATLAB to Linux and vice versa in a shell

Tags: bash, matlab, shell, parsing

I have encountered a problem. I have to use MATLAB with linux.
I need to parse data from MATLAB to Linux and vice versa.

For exammple

This all is writtein in

```
basic.sh

this basic.sh has to be opened in MATLAB

 s=3     # is defined is MATLAB
##########################


for (( p=1 ; p<5; p++ ))     # from here starts the loop in Linux
do                                # is a command from Linux
echo "$p"                         # is a command from Linux
add= $p+s                         # should calulate in linux , is a command from Linux
add=add/5                         # should do in MATLAB 
done     

#########################
 add                              # should OUTPUT the value of add as there is no semicolumn in MATLAB
```

Kindly suggest me a possible way for such a small example the rest I will expand it myself.

best regards

Comment: Doesn't matlab have equivalent functionality for what you are trying to do in bash?

Comment: @chepner I am using a simulation software that generates some data- I have to optimize and manipulate that data. In order to do that I have to write a shell script. Since shell script has problems with the manipulation of real numbers, I thought it would be better if I can combine the POWERS of both softwares. Thats why I have written that I will extend it to my need. I need just a start and a possible way.

Comment: Aha! So, the **real** problem is how you're doing your math in that shell script. You could of course ask a question on SO with the `bash` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can call Matlab from a terminal, and run a single command:

```
$ matlab -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash -r <YOUR_COMMAND>
```

in which `<YOUR_COMMAND>` can be an m-script/function. The output of this can be redirected into shellscripts,

```
$ matlab -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash -r <YOUR_COMMAND> | ./basic.sh
```

(your script should be capable of handling pipes), or this entire command can be embedded in shell scripts,

```
#!/bin/bash

s=$(matlab -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash -r <FUNCTION_GENERATING_S>)

<code generating $add>

result=$(matlab -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash -r <SOME_FUNCTION($add)>)
```

You can of course also resort to using files as memory. Matlab part:

```
s=3;      

fid = fopen('TMP.txt','w');
fprintf(fid, s);
fclose(fid);

!./basic.sh

fid = fopen('TMP.txt','r');
add = fscanf(fid, '%f');
fclose(fid);
```

Shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

s=$(cat TMP.txt)
for (( p=1; p<5; p++ ))     
do                            
    echo "$p" 
    add=$(($p+$s))
    add=add/5                      
done

echo $add > TMP.txt
```

Advantage of this is that there is a strict separation between Matlab and shell script, and only one m-file will suffice.

Of course, whichever way you choose -- why would you want to do this in the first place? Matlab can do most of what bash is capable of, and is also platform independent (so if you switch to MS Windows, it all still works)...so can you clarify this a bit?

Comment: I am using a simulation software that generates some data- I have to optimize and manipulate that data. That software run on a server which is linux based. In order to do that I have to write a shell script. Since shell script has problems with the manipulation of real numbers, I thought it would be better if I can combine the POWERS of both softwares. Thats why I have written that I will extend it to my need. I need just a start and a possible way.

Comment: is it not possible to use in some way the commands of MATLAB inside a shell script? I mean not calling the MATLAB function rather some commands?

Comment: @hamadkhan How would you write working C++ code in a shell script? You can't! The question is: why would you want to? Use the right tool for the job. If you really need advanced numerical manipulation in Matlab, you'll have to put everything the script does in an m-file and forget about the script.

Comment: You can certainly use bash as the glue layer between the simulation software that generates the data, and Matlab that analyzes the data. Another alternative was suggested by Rody; just use files as a way to coordinate between the two pieces; generate data to a file; then load it all up in matlab and analyze.